# How to start a long running JAR in CloudFormation cfn-init?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to start a Spring boot server with a JAR file.
Generally this is executed with `java -jar springboot.jar &`

However I am having trouble doing this using CloudFormation and this does not appear to work.

I am trying to do it in `cfn-init` this way:

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
    "config" : {
        "commands": {
            "start_server": {
                "command": "bash startup_script.sh &",
                "cwd": "/home/ec2-user"
             }
        }
```

But the init does not go through.

Comment: What's stopping you from executing `java -jar springboot.jar &` as a command?

Comment: Is the problem that CloudFormation stops before the script finishes or it does not even run?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. The formation does not go through. It times out. I cant get to logs to see what is happening. But I have narrowed it down to the java -jar command.

Answer (score 1):

I think using userdata property of ec2 would suffice in this case. However if you need more help in generating the cumbersome AWS::CloudFormation::Init object, you can use [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) which is an online cloudformation template generator.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to add a `CreationPolicy` and set the time-out as needed

```
CreationPolicy:
    ResourceSignal:
      Count: '3'
      Timeout: PT15M
```

Adjust as you need. I've used this in cfn-init blocks that needed to do tasks that could take half an hour.